# unexpected token ( using modular pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/4qv24djp/1/

```
var module_pattern = (function() {
  var private = 'private';

  a: function() {
      console.log('function a and the private variable is ' + private);
    },

    b: function() {

    }

  return {
    a: a
  }
})();

module_pattern.a();
```

What's wrong with above code? I expect it will print the console of function `a`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You declared the variables with `:` whereas you need to use a `=`. The colon is only used within object declarations. You also did not end the line with a `;` but with a `,`. Variables `a` and `b` need a `var` in front of them. Otherwise, they will be globally accessible and that's exactly what you wouldn't want with the modular pattern.

See the working fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/4qv24djp/3/

```
var module_pattern = (function() {
    var private = 'private';

    var a = function() {
      console.log('function a and the private variable is ' + private);
    };

    var b = function() {

    };

    return {
        a: a
    }
})();

module_pattern.a();
```

You could also directly return the functions in an object:

```
var module_pattern = (function() {
    var private = 'private';

    return {
        a: function() {
            console.log('function a and the private variable is ' + private);
        },
        b: function() {

        }
    };
})();

module_pattern.a();
```

Comment: can I pass param to my module? like this https://jsfiddle.net/4qv24djp/6/. I got undefined btw..

Comment: @AliciaBrandon You are expecting the param at the wrong place: You are calling the `a()` function, so you need to add the param there: `var a = function(name) { ... }`

Comment: @AliciaBrandon The modular pattern is mainly to encapsulate the code into one module. It is often used as a good practice to pass the dependencies of a module to the module function, e.g.: `var module_pattern = (function($, angular) { ... })($, angular);`

Comment: can you show in jsfiddle? why pass in both bracket?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare variables and functions as variable = 'variable' and not varaiable:variable.

```js
var module_pattern = (function() {
  var private = 'private';

  var a = function() {
      console.log('function a and the private variable is '  + private);
    };

  var  b = function() {

    };

  return {
    a: a
  }
})();

module_pattern.a();
```